# Swagger 2.1 without Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jaxb, swagger, jsonb

I have a `JAX-RS` web service which I want to document with `Swagger 2.1`.
Currently this is only possible if I also include Jackson.

Is there a possibility to use `Swagger 2.1` without `Jackson` and by default with `Jaxb` and `Jsonb`.
Without `Jackson` I currently get the following exception on the start of the application:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter.enabled()Z
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.hasAnySetter (JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:1262)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addMethods (POJOPropertiesCollector.java:538)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll (POJOPropertiesCollector.java:309)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getPropertyMap (POJOPropertiesCollector.java:287)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getProperties (POJOPropertiesCollector.java:170)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription._properties (BasicBeanDescription.java:164)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.findProperties (BasicBeanDescription.java:239)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._findCreatorsFromProperties (BasicDeserializerFactory.java:292)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._constructDefaultValueInstantiator (BasicDeserializerFactory.java:276)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findValueInstantiator (BasicDeserializerFactory.java:224)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer (BeanDeserializerFactory.java:220)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer (BeanDeserializerFactory.java:143)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2 (DeserializerCache.java:411)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer (DeserializerCache.java:349)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2 (DeserializerCache.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer (DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer (DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findNonContextualValueDeserializer (DeserializationContext.java:466)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve (BeanDeserializerBase.java:473)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2 (DeserializerCache.java:293)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer (DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer (DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer (DeserializationContext.java:476)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer (ObjectMapper.java:4389)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose (ObjectMapper.java:4198)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue (ObjectMapper.java:3205)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue (ObjectMapper.java:3173)
    at io.swagger.v3.oas.integration.ContextUtils.deepCopy (ContextUtils.java:18)
```

My `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer-v2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```